# Multi selection Tree in .NET ( visible in UIA ) with win32 treeview?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, frameworks, automation, treeview

I need a treeview in .net with supported multi selection.
A own implementation in wpf or winforms ( this two don't have multi selection out of the box !? ) is a no go, i need the multi selection visible in the ms ui automation framework.

Do anyone know if this is possible with the win32 treeview ? Or know a way how to implement multiselection in wpf / winforms which is also visible in the automation framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, even the awesome Infragistics controls are visible to the UI automation framework, but I think you need to use the 'core classes' with the legacy msaa pattern (that is what I do with Infragistics and Ui Automation).

As far as something more friendly and free, I'd suggest trying this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20581/Multiselect-Treeview-Implementation

I use it and have been very happy with it.  I don't actually automate it, but use it elsewhere.  I would think that it is UI Automation friendly, though, based on looking at the code a bit.

Comment: i already used this example, the problem is the same, in the UIA the other selected notes are not marked with haskeyboardfocus and the accessible state is not "selected" so no way for me to check which items are selected in a multi selection scenario :O i hoped i could find a out of the box solution without including the provider interfaces.

Comment: not sure if this will help you, but it looks to me like the expandcollapsepattern, selectionitempattern, & scrollitempattern are supported.  you might find what you need if you try using those patterns.